# Gaussian09 and Path Integral Monte Carlo which one predicts the total internal energy more accurately?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I'm learning PIMC with primitive action and currently just testing the code with single methane molecule, I did run a Gaussian ccsd(t) calculation, I notice that at 298.15K & 1atm, the energy predicted by PIMC(0.0476a.u.) is slightly lower than the one by Gaussian(0.0477a.u.) both errors start from 5th decimal number. I'm just wondering which result could be more reliable? And why one is more reliable than the other?
It might be a dumb question, but I don't see anywhere made such comparison and I'm just an undergraduate student with no experience with either of two computational techniques. Would be greatly appreciated if can use some expertise!

Comment: what energy are you calculating? what are the parameters of your pimc calculation (grid)? what basis set do you use in your cc calculation? convergence criteria?

Comment: Total internal energy is the one I'm calculating. Grid approach to PIMC...


cc-PVTZ for H  
aug-cc-PVTZ for C  

I'm not sure what you mean by convergence criteria, I ran an extremely long simulation then I applied the "Flyvbjerg-Petersen"blocking algorithm to work out the number of  samples required to reach convergence

Comment: Every time you look for convergence you stop if the change between two (or more) points is less than a certain value. For SCF convergence in Gaussian use the keyword SCF=(Conver=N) which sets the SCF convergence criteria to 10^-N, see http://www.gaussian.com/g_tech/g_ur/k_scf.htm.
I guess you are doing single point calculations?

Comment: @DSVA I get your first point, in which case, the "Flyvbjerg-Petersen"Blocking algorithm is a very computational efficient way to do it.  As total energy is the bottom of the well, so single point is the easiest way? But later on, for PIMC, I guess I can apply modified Shepard interpolation to grow PES, which is something beyond me atm.

Comment: Single point energy means that you calculate the energy at a specific geometry which you use as input for your calculation. In contrast to that you can also do a geometry optimization. If you do that there could also be an error in finding the lowest energy structure in addition to calculating the energy.

Comment: And the thing about the convergence criteria: let's say your real value is 1 and you start with 20 and your convergence criteria would a be change of less than 0.05 between to points. Your algorithm would do something like 20, 11, 5, 2.81, 1.95, 1.40, 1.22, 1.11, 1.07 and there it stops. The difference between 1.07 and 1.11 is below 0.05. But if you got a tighter criterion of let's say <0.02 then it won't stop there and it would go on like 1.04, 1.02, 1.01 , which is much better.

Comment: @DSVA I think the single point was done by someone who previously worked on the project, and its accuracy was checked by a few groups, I can't provide further detail about it as I don't have much knowledge about this. But in regard to your 2nd comment, this is exactly what Blocking algorithm does, in a slightly smarter way, it works especially well when the simulation is massive. Perhaps read the paper J. Chem. Phys. 91, 461 (1989); [link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.457480)

Comment: Can you add your G09 input to your post? And yes, both methods do that but the question is what the convergence criteria are! If for MC it's extremly tight and for G09 it's not then it doesn't make sense to compare them! Make the convergence criteria tighter and look if the results change.

Comment: One problem in comparing the two methods is also that MC uses statistics and CCSD(T) is an ab-initio method. CCSD(T) is often used as a reference/benchmark value for other calculations since it is highly accurate.

Comment: @GavyLittlewolf Can you please edit your question to inclde EVERY paramter you are using in both methods? Discretization of grid, all appropriate CC convergence criteria etc. And all the settings you made. If you also pass over the coordination file of your molecule I can make a CCSD(T) calc with TURBOMOLE and maybe get some more info for you. But I personally would always trust a CCSD(T) with a good setup more than a MC

Comment: @Fl.pf let me get back to you guys, I figured there are some more PIMC calculation can be done before making the comparison. I will update as soon I have the result. Sorry for the waiting!